# Accidentally overwrote first 400MB of hard drive with ext3 partition - possible to rescue?

Tags: hard-drive, ext3, data-recovery, partition-table

Accidentally wrote /dev/zero to the first 371MB of a 500GB disk. Is it possible to rebuild the partition table and/or recover what data hasn't been overwritten?

Answer (score 1):

try [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk), this is pretty much the only tool that can save something off ext3

Answer (score 0):

If only the first part of disk overwriten, the bacup superblock may help you

1. you could use `mke2fs -n` /dev/sdx to see the superblock location
2. if all backup superblock `mke2fs -n` provide is wrong, you could scan it `hexdump /dev/sdx| awk '$6 == "ef53"'`
   for example

```
0000430 9eb6 6465 0000 ffff ef53 0001 0001 0000
8000030 9eb6 6465 0000 ffff ef53 0000 0001 0000
...
```

`0x0000400(0000430-30)` is main superblock,`0x8000000(8000030-30)` is backup superblock
if block size is 4k(0x1000), superblock of `8000030` is `(0x8000030-0x30)/0x1000=32768`

verify by `dumpe2fs -o superblock=32768/dev/sdx`, if it dump information, it may be the filesystem you are using.

3. e2fsck  -b 32768 /dev/sdx to fix superblock and continue fsck.